# Read Windows file digital signature time stamp in Ubuntu

Tags: windows, signature

I am trying to automate downloading the monthly Microsoft cab file for windows updates via my ubuntu server.

I would like to verify the digital signature before marking it as good (last few months MS has been screwing it up.

Windows has a tool called signtool. Is there an equivalent tool or another process?

(I am currently running Ubuntu 15.04)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`osslsigncode`](https://github.com/mtrojnar/osslsigncode) for this. It’s not available in your version of Ubuntu, only in [16.10 and later](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/osslsigncode); but it’s easy to build.

To verify a signature, run it as

```
osslsigncode verify filetoverify
```

Comment: When I run the above command it tells me `Command is not supported for non-PE/non-MSI files`.